# Is it possible to configure a location in Web.config to deny all my country except my ip and also allowing the rest of the world?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I've got a page in an ASP.Net app and I would like to deny connections from my country but allowing my personal ip to this page from the local machine. 
 Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't block by country. Instead, you can block by IP ranges.

Comment: i made it by range, but my ip continue deny

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
<remove ipAdress="192.168.23.111"/>   (this is my ip)
<clear/>
<add ipAddress="2.18.64.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>
<add ipAddress="2.19.251.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>
   (and rest of ip's from my country)